# Subtotal vs Aggregate Function

Tags: visualforce, soql, controller

I have created a custom object `Commission_Rec__c` with a master/detail relationship with a custom child object of `Order_Entry__c`.  What I am trying to do is create a vf page that will display information from the `Commission_Rec__c` object along with a listing of the `Order_Entry_c` records associated with it but also subtotaled by one of the fields (`Sales_rep__c`) but still displaying certain fields from each record of the `Order_Entry_c` object.  Basically a related list but with a subtotal.  The end game is to have a button on the `Commission_Rec__c` object that will call the vf page rendered as a PDF.

I have created a public class that pulls the `Order_Entry_c` records using the Aggregrate Results/group by rollup function but it summarizes the information.  I need the subtotal functionality but I also need to see the individual `Order_Entry_c` records.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: GROUP BY ROLLUP is the key here and you're on the right track. You'd have to post your code to get further assistance. You will ultimately need two queries if you want to use an aggregate query, one for the actual records and one for the totals. Alternatively, you can compute the subtotals yourself by looping through the records.  How do you want subtotals displayed? By groupings within the child list or just as a grand total at the bottom of the entire child list?

Comment: Bryan were you able to get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

AggregateResults will always rollup like that. If you want subtotals as well as individual records you can either use two different queries, or just query for the records and add them up yourself.

Comment: AggregateResult[] AgR = [SELECT Sales_Person__c, Invoice_No__c, Invoice_Date__c, SUM(Total__c), SUM(Commission_Paid__c) FROM Order_Entry__c                       WHERE Comm_Rec_del__r.id=:commrec.ID                             GROUP BY ROLLUP (Sales_Person__c, Invoice_No__c, Invoice_Date__c)]; for (AggregateResult SalesList : AgR)

Comment: The code works and brings back what you would expect but what I am trying to do is have the Sales_Person__c Subtotaled but just display each Invoice_No__c and Invoice_Date__c value.  If I use the Group by Rollup above I get a separate subtotal row for each Invoice No.  It works fine if I only Group by the Sales Person and Invoice Number but then I can't display the Invoice Date.

Comment: When you say use two queries can I combine the results and have a subtotal for each Sales Person and a Grand Total at the end?